# How to create android tablet application using monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new to monodroid , my doubt is how to create android tablet application using mondroid ?

I can create the application for 2.3.3 but in monodroid there is no options to target the android version for developement, as a result i can not create application targeted for tablet application.

Can you please advise how to create tablet application using monodroid ?

Answer (score 0):

In Android devices, a tablet is exactly the same as a phone, except with a larger screen. (This is not strictly true though). To determine if a device is a tablet, you must see what the screen dimensions are.

It is not like the iOS that has a iPad and a iPhone, Android has a device with a smaller/larger screen.

Android 2.3.3 is for both tablets and phones. They split it into 3.x for tablets, and joined them again with 4.x. So you shouldn't find a phone running 3.x, but you will find both a tablet and a phone with 2.3.3 or 4.0.

From the docs ([Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)):

- 320dp: typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc)
- 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
- 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
- 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

More cool docs: [Supporting Tablets and Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

if your application is only for tablet-style devices with a 600dp smallest available width:

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

However, if your application supports all screen sizes supported by Android (as small as 426dp x 320dp), then you don't need to declare this attribute, because the smallest width your application requires is the smallest possible on any device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matthew.
Actually i was looking for options to target application to android 3.1 like similar to eclipse IDE but i found solution to do it.
Can you please advise tutorials for developing application for android tablets (3.X) using monodroid. ?

Comment: I am not too sure about tutorials, but you should be able to find many on the net. - Please either accept this answer, or answer you own question on how you achieved a solution.

Comment: Did you use the Android Manifest (from the Project Properties) to set the minimum SDK version to 3.0?

Comment: Under project build settings -> general there is an option to set the target framework to 3.1(honeycomb).
i'm not able to find tutorials for 3.1 developement using monodroid on net.. could you please share some.!!

Comment: Follow the normal Android documentation, most of that is applicable in Mono for Android as it wraps the Android implementations. Here is a list of changes: http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/11/changes.html So just code normally and if you use any of those classes, take a look at the changes and how they are implemented.

Comment: i have created tutorial for solution to this problem on my blog.
http://www.akiievolution.com/how-to-change-default-target-framework-for-monodroid-application/

Comment: Remember, Android 4.x also works on the phones, so this didn't ready solve the problem of "tablet only". You do need to specify a minimum screen size if not all the content can fit on a phone screen.